# How to interrupt current CSS animation and start another?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, toast

I have the following example code which creates toasts that fly out from the top of the screen, stay for a few seconds, and then fly away:

```js
function createToast() {
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("toast");
  elem.innerText = "hello";

  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  setTimeout(() => elem.remove(), 3000);
}

setInterval(createToast, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.toast {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;

  animation-name: toastin, toastout;
  animation-duration: 0.3s, 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, 1;
  animation-delay: 0s, 2.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes toastin {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
}

@keyframes toastout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50vw, 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body><body>
```

This works fine, but sometimes in my application another toast will be created before the current one is gone. In that case, I want the current toast to fly away immediately upon the creation of the new toast, instead of waiting 2.5 seconds.

For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. Is it possible? It seems so simple, but nothing I try seems to have any effect.

First I tried grabbing the existing toast element and setting the `animation-delay` to `0s`, but that had no effect. Then I tried replacing it with an entire new animation, tried using `!important`, etc. In all cases the toast just, like, disappears, with no animation happening.

Is there any way to just make the toast immediately finish its current animation in like 0.4 seconds when a new toast is created? So that it flies away before it collides with the incoming toast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some adjustments to your approach:

1. Instead of assigning both of the animations at the same time, only assign the `toastout` animation to a certain class, let's say `.out`.
2. When trying to remove a toast, call function `removeToast()`. It adds class `.out` to that toast. So you can control when to play the `toastout` animation, then after the animation is played, remove the element using event `animationend`.
3. Each time a new toast is added, try to call `removeToast()` on every existing toast.

Here's the full solution:

```js
function createToast() {
  // remove all existing toasts
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.toast')].forEach(removeToast);
  
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("toast");
  elem.innerText = "hello";
  setTimeout(() => removeToast(elem), 3000);
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

function removeToast(toast) {
  // if a toast is already removed, ignore
  if (!toast || toast.classList.contains('out')) return;
  
  toast.classList.add('out');
  toast.addEventListener('animationend', () => toast.remove());
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.toast {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;

  animation-name: toastin;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.toast.out {
  animation-name: toastout;
}

@keyframes toastin {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
}

@keyframes toastout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50vw, 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="createToast()">Add toast</button>
<body>
```

Comment: Oh, this is brilliant! Thanks so much! This looks great and contains many good ideas that will greatly improve the quality of my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to elem and remove it when the function is called again. Maybe something like this:

```
let activeToast;

function clearToast() {
  if(!activeToast){
     return;
  }
  activeToast.remove();
  activeToast = null;
}

function createToast() {
  clearToast();
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("toast");
  elem.innerText = "hello";
  activeToast = elem;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  setTimeout(() => clearToast(), 3000);
}

setInterval(createToast, 3000);
```

But if you want to keep track of the animation itself there are some animation events you might want to use.

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/css-animation-events-in-javascript-d2bfe702636d

Comment: Oh, I'm not having any issues deleting the element from the DOM. What I am trying to do is make it skip the 2.5 second animation delay when another toast quickly appears.

Comment: edited my answer. I think you are looking for animation events

Answer (score 0):

You'd think it's possible, right? Maybe you need to add a variable to check whether there's a toast being displayed or not. If there's a toast being displayed, you can apply elem.remove() right away to only show the new toast. Check below to see if that works for you.

```js
let isToastDisplayed = false;

function createToast() {
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("toast");
  elem.innerText = "hello";

  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  if (isToastDisplayed) {
    const currentToast = document.querySelector(".toast");
    currentToast.remove();
  }

  isToastDisplayed = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    elem.remove();
    isToastDisplayed = false;
  }, 3000);
}

setInterval(createToast, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.toast {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;

  animation-name: toastin, toastout;
  animation-duration: 0.3s, 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, 1;
  animation-delay: 0s, 2.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes toastin {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
}

@keyframes toastout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50vw, 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body><body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this directly answer your question but you might be able to separate the animation out on a separate class... then with js you can check for existing ones and add the class out!

check it out

```js
function createToast() {
const existing = document.querySelectorAll('.toast')
if(existing.length > 0) {
existing.forEach(e => {
e.classList.add('toast-out')
})
}
  const elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.classList.add("toast");
  elem.innerText = "hello";

  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  setTimeout(() => elem.remove(), 3000);
}

setInterval(createToast, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.toast {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;

  animation-name: toastin;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.toast-out {
animation-name: toastout;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes toastin {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -40px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
}

@keyframes toastout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50vw, 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body><body>
```